Is there a shared component to display a context menu in .NET MAUI for Android / iOS?
Is there any native component to replicate this functionality that currently only works on desktop?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/context-menu?view=net-maui-8.0
According to the documentation, this component only works for desktop, but I would like to use it in my MAUI app
As shown in this screenshot:



Is there a shared component to display a context menu in .NET MAUI for Android / iOS?

Yes, and you can refer to this discussion on MAUI GitHub: How to display a Context Menu on a Mobile Device #10752. Use components that discussion mentioned: 
ContextMenuContainer | Maui.ContextMenu.
And also this GitHub repository.

Thank you, I'll test it and come back to mark it as answered.

You can also see this case: How can I add a context menu to UI element in MAUI?.
